# I have sinned and need help

Tags: sin

recently I went astray, which I regret. I got involved in things I never should have. I was seeing a guy which I have known from my middle eastern community and hung out with friends behind my mother's back. After a while, my younger sister went on my phone while i was sleeping and took pictures of my text messages and gave them to my mom. Ever since, my life has changed. My relationship with my mom is nonexistent and no one in the house talks to me. I have turned to Allah repenting and asking for forgiveness, constantly listening to the Quran and so on. I have been in so much regret, I haven't eaten for three days and I have lost all sense of motivation in life. I made a mistake and I don't know how else to go about this. I feel so guilty. Does anyone have any suggestions, advice?

Comment: I think it may have been wrong for you to do so but it is also extreme on your family’s side to leave you like that. If possible try to reconcile you relationship with your mother but if that isn’t possible I would advise you to try keep close bonds with other family members. Also starving yourself is obviously not good for health so you cannot do so. If it impacts your mental well-being I would suggest visiting a therapist or simple to lectures by scholars about mercy, forgiveness etc. I don’t have any links but  I’m sure someone may have something.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum My Dear Sister! we all sin throughout and there is no angel among us. As a result, in Islam, a repenting sinner is referred as the best of the sinners. Take the following Hadith:

Prophet Muhammed has said: “Every son of Adam sins and the best of those who sin are those who repent.” [Al-Tirmidhi, no. 2499]

Now I am going to give you some links which will help you overcome the shock you have got from your surroundings and hope that you will, In Sha Allah recover and return to the path of Simplicity : The Sirat Al Mustakim.

At first, Take these hadiths on repentance from [***here***](https://themuslimvibe.com/faith-islam/read-these-8-beautiful-hadiths-on-repentance-%F0%9F%99%8F%F0%9F%8F%BC)

Then watch these videos with a calm mind:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-pSv9w32FY (Repent, Allah Loves you!)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNRFo1JXIJw (You are Forgiven, move on!)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ght7mTGtYyc (A story of Repentance)

In Sha Allah, You will get to know that in Islam, Allah never forsakes you even if you have sins equaling to the Mountain. So, come back to Islam properly and engage in worship of Allah in such a way that Shaitaan may never dare to make you indulge in sin ever again!